# QuickReplies as slotfilling for dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I am building a conversation in dialogflow where I would like to predefine answers for slotfilling in the same way as Quickreplies work, so that the user get buttons to click on to fill in the slots instead of the filling in the slots by writing. Is this possible to do in Dialogflow?

I have googled alot but i don't really know what to google..

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using slotfilling from fulfillment:

https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-slot-filling-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js